# How to append a number to the end of duplicated lines in bash shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, scripting

If I have a file containing the following lines:

```
orange
apple
mango
orange
mango
orange
```

How do I append a number to each duplicate line to get:

```
orange
apple
mango
orange 2
mango 2
orange 3
```

Using bash script? Thank you in advance, I am new to writing scripts.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure bash solution: use an associative array.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A seen
while read line ; do
    if ((seen[$line]++)) ; then
        echo "$line ${seen[$line]}"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

Or, using Perl:

```
perl -pe '$seen{$_}++ and s/$/ $seen{$_}/'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints it after processing
- the hash `%seen` keeps the number of times a string's been seen. If it's not seen for the first time, when the `++` operator returns false, the number is appended to the line to be printed.

Comment: Thanks! How do I append it within the file, rather than printing it out using echo?

Comment: Redirect the output to a new file, rename the new file to the old name.